# What is the difference between using the == operator and the Equals method on a boxed boolean type?

Tags: c#, boxing

Given these two statements...

```
((object)false) == ((object)false)
((object)false).Equals((object)false)
```

The first statement returns false.
The second statement returns true.

I understand why the first statement returns false - when the boolean is boxed, it becomes a reference type, and the two references are not equal. But, why / how does the second statement result in true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's still calling the polymorphic `Equals` method, basically.

Sample code to demonstrates with a different type:

```
using System;

struct Foo
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.Equals called!");
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object first = new Foo();
        object second = new Foo();
        first.Equals(second);
    }
}
```

That still prints "Foo.Equals called!" because calling the Equals method on the "box" still calls `Foo.Equals`.

Now `==` isn't *overridden*, it's *overloaded*... so if you write:

```
object first = ...;
object second = ...;
bool same = first == second;
```

That will *always* compare for reference identity, without *ever* running any type-specific code.

Answer (score 5):

This article may be able to answer your question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just as you said, the first example checks whether the references are equal, while the second checks for equal values for each object.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the Equals method. In the list, x, y, and z represent object references that are not null.
>
> x.Equals(x) returns true, except in cases that involve floating-point types. See IEC 60559:1989, Binary Floating-point Arithmetic for Microprocessor Systems.
>
> x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).
>
> x.Equals(y) returns true if both x and y are NaN.
>
> If (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true, then x.Equals(z) returns true.
>
> Successive calls to x.Equals(y) return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y are not modified.
>
> x.Equals(null) returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading is not polymorphic but `Equals` is.  Even though `bool` has an overloaded ==, by casting it to `object` you're using `object`'s implementation, which compares reference equality.  But you're still using the `bool` version of `Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Equals` method is a virtual method which is overridden by the `Boolean` type. So it doesn't matter that you're casting the `bool` to an `object` in the second line; it's still using the type's vtable to look up the implementation of `Equals` provided by the object's *actual* type (that's polymorphism for you!).

The `==` operator is a **static operator** and so the appropriate overload is selected at compile time. The compiler sees you comparing two objects of type `object` with that operator and so it selects the `(object, object)` overload.

Here's a stupid little program to illustrate the difference:

```
class Thing
{
    public virtual void AnnounceSelf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Thing.");
    }

    public static void AnnounceThing(Thing other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is a Thing.");
    }

    public static void AnnounceThing(OtherThing other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is ANOTHER type of Thing.");
    }
}

class OtherThing : Thing
{
    public override void AnnounceSelf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am ANOTHER Thing.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thing t = new Thing();

        // Outputs "I am a Thing." as expected.
        t.AnnounceSelf();

        // Outputs "Here is a Thing." as expected.
        Thing.AnnounceThing(t);

        t = new OtherThing();

        // This method is virtual, so even though t is typed as Thing,
        // the implementation provided by OtherThing will be called;
        // outputs "I am ANOTHER Thing."
        t.AnnounceSelf();

        // In contrast to above, this method will NOT call the more
        // specific overload of AnnounceThing (accepting an OtherThing
        // argument) because t is only typed as Thing, so the compiler
        // will go with the first;
        // outputs "Here is a Thing."
        Thing.AnnounceThing(t);

        // THIS will output "Here is ANOTHER type of Thing."
        Thing.AnnounceThing((OtherThing)t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1st one is for references, second one is for values!